# Find the URLs of the media being used in a webpage

Tags: firefox

Firefox used to have a way of displaying all media that was used on the page. It was useful to save images, that were loaded using JavaScript.

E.g. I want to download the logo for Signal on https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/signal-private-messenger/id874139669

Here I cannot simply left-click and save image. I used to be able to find this in media list, but that functionality seems to be gone (or at least hidden).

What is the easiest way of finding the URLs of media used in a page (such as images)?

Comment: It's actually a square image with a rounded mask applied to it via CSS. You can `right-click -> inspect element` on it and look through the HTML code if you never want to rely on add-ons again...

Answer (score 0):

Linky has been there for long and does its job smoothly for the price of a right click.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/linky/